# Does a live CD exist for Windows 7 that allows me to add a local user account

Tags: windows-7

Basically I need a Windows 7 live cd that will allow me to add a local user account.

Does such a thing exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows XP there was a software called ERD Commander which actually worked.

But I think that you can try to boot with the default Windows 7 and on recovery console just add a user by running:

```
Net users <username> <password> /ADD 
net localgroup "administrators" "<username>" /add
```

… to get it on the admin group

Comment: Recovery console worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

There are also password eraser live cds with this functionality, although last time I tried I ran into problems (couldn't unlock account) and had to use Ophcrack (fortunately there was another admin account).  But that would not happen if you are just adding a user, not clearing passwords, I believe.

Search Engine: 'windows 7 password eraser live cd' and pick your poison

Comment: Could you actually tell us an eraser? We highly discourage telling people to "go google it"

Comment: I don't quite remember.  Might have been this:  http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/  Not sure whether the other password crackers have this functionality, since I haven't tried them.